# Infinite loop on list item in unordered list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops, carousel

I have this list of item

```
<div id="lessonThree">
<a class="next" href="#">Next</a>

 <ul class="sponsors">
    <li>Chicago Community Trust</li>
    <li>Chicago Instructional Technology Foundation</li>
    <li>City of Chicago</li>
    <li>Corporation for Public Broadcasting</li>
    <li>U.S. Department of Energy</li>
    <li>Ford Foundation</li>
    <li>Google</li>
    <li>Intel</li>
    <li>Knight Foundation</li>
    <li>MacArthur Foundation</li>
    <li>National Endowment for the Arts</li>
    <li>NESTA</li>
    <li>The Nominet Trust</li>
    <li>National Science Foundation</li>
    <li>Ontario Trillium Foundation</li>
    <li>Social Science Research Council</li>
    <li>Alfred P. Sloan Foundation</li>
    <li>Telefonica</li>
    <li>ZeroDivide</li>
  </ul>    
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is that I want to set a limit of how many item should be display at the time.

```
var MAX_ITEM = someNumbers // this will be define in the javascript file
```

So if say they have the maximum item to display at the time is : `3` what I really want is to let them `fadeIn` using jQuery one by one and when it reaches the MAX_ITEM I want that to have a delay of say `1500` millseconds using setTimeOut or something similar to display that for a bit then the three of the items will be `fadeOut` and starting the next three items and so on as an infinite loop.

The `next` button is to be used to speed to the next item as if they want to make it move faster.

I used to use this plugin `CarofredSel` but really that impact a lot of page load in our webapp, and it has a lot of restriction on the style which I can't really control.

Can anyone suggest me a way or any example, so that I can accomplish this?

This is the code I was starting with

```
$('ul > li').each(function(i, element) {
    $(element).delay(i * 2000).fadeIn();
});
```

But the above code will only loop through each of the list items and then will stop at the end.

### Update:

I have did a bit more research "On Stackoverflow" There are a lot of good examples and this is one closest to what I want, but I can't accomplish what I want exactly.

```
var counter = 0;
var limit = 3;

function fadeInSequence(li){
    var next = $(li).next('li')!=null?function(){fadeInSequence($(li).next('li'));}:function(){};
    $(li).fadeIn(2000,next);
    counter++;
    if(counter == limit){

        counter = 0;
    }

}
fadeInSequence($('.sponsors>li:first'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zdqCz/84/

The above code will `fadeIn` through all the items in the list, but not infinite and what I want now here is the same as the above where I want to only display 3 items then `fadeOut` and show the next 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your update was a good start... I adapted it to include 3 items (jquery selector) rather than 1 and added a fadeOut on the callback of fadeIn to achieve the cycle what you were looking for.  After the callback reaches the end of the list, we start over. See below

```
function fadeInSequence($three) {
    //default to the first three list items
    if ($three == null) $three = $('.sponsors>li:lt(3)');

    //fade in the 3 found
    $three.fadeIn(2000, function () {
        //fade out the 3 after fadein and start
        $(this).fadeOut(2000);
    }).promise().done(function () {
        if ($three.last().nextAll(':lt(3)').length) {
            //Same function, next 3 items
            fadeInSequence($three.last().nextAll(':lt(3)'));
        } else {
            //Same function, from the beginning if none are left
            fadeInSequence();
        }
    });
}

$(function () {
    //start the infinite looping
    fadeInSequence();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3DTC/4/

For a fadeIn for each of the 3 items:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q3DTC/6/

Comment: @r0rn4n That was great!, but one thing if I asked you how can I accomplish this: How can I make it fadeIn one by one and not three at the same time?

Comment: @KyleMuir changing that will only make it display one at the time, but what I really want it to happen is to make it one by one (max to three) then start off from one by one again

Comment: It is awesome! :D One quick question though (Accepted your answer anyway). If you wait and see the last it is actually only shows up with one item because obviously the number is only left off with one, but is there a way that it could pick up the next two as well?